# How can one specify the value type for an OCaml map

Tags: module, ocaml

I want to declare ahead of time the value type for a map type.

The functor `Map.Make` returns a `Map.S` with two type definitions:

```
type key
type !+'a t
```

Type `'a` appears to be the type of values in the map. For example, this is the function for adding a key (of type `key` and value of type `'a`:

```
    val add: key -> 'a -> 'a t -> 'a t
```

One can write the key type like this:

```ml
module type M = Map.S with type key = string
```

But I couldn't figure out how to specify the value type. This isn't valid syntax:

```ml
module type M = Map.S with type key = string  and 'a = int
```

Comment: Seems a little like an XY problem. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: My original motivation was to write types down so my code is readable. In other languages, I'd write something like `type Scope = HashMap<String, Ty>;` (Rust) or  `type Scope = Map[String, Ty]` (Scala). But now my primary motivation is just to understand OCaml better.

Comment: The `Map` module doesn't quiote work the same way, though. Consider `module M = Map.Make (struct type t = int let compare = compare end)`. I can now do both: ` M.(empty |> add 45 37.3 |> iter (fun k _ -> Printf.printf "%d\n" k))` _and_ ` M.(empty |> add 45 "hello" |> iter (fun k _ -> Printf.printf "%d\n" k))`, _but_ I cannot get away wirth trying tto add values of different types to the same map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to look at this is that you're trying to impose monomorphism in the wrong place. The essence of Map.S is that it's polymorphic in the element type.

You can easily define a type for maps from string keys to int values:

```
# module M = Map.Make(String);;
. . .
# type string_int_mod = int M.t;;
type string_int_mod = int M.t

# let f (m: string_int_mod) s i = M.add s i m;;
val f : string_int_mod -> M.key -> int -> int M.t = <fun>
```

In many cases, the polymorphism inferred by OCaml is clearer than specifically ascribed types. At least in my opinion. The types inferred by OCaml tell you what the code is really doing and where it has degrees of freedom.